# How to copy the text from certain Website with python?

Tags: python, php, html, web

i want to copy the text from this Website (https://www.reclamgymnasium.de/mobil/plankl.html?Klasse=9.2), to use it later py script.
How can i do this? (It doesent realy work with request...)

Answer (score 0):

If you google about python webscraping you will find a lot of information!

basically you start by executing

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

Which provides you with the html content of the webpage. Now you can use beautifulsoup to navigate through the content to get what you need.

First we need to create a soup:

```
soup = beautifulsoup(response.text, "lxml")
```

in which we can now find the content. If we for example want to find all the url's in the webpage, you can use:

```
soup.find_all('a')
```

Here is a complete example code for printing all the url's of a webpage:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://google.com"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link)
```

Here is the documentation of beautifulsoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: It works but not how i want it because it just gives me some content not all (not the content i need)

Comment: you can change the 'a' to whatever part of the page you need. Could you elaborate on what you need from the website?

Comment: i know but the websitecontet that i want is dynamic so it doesent work...

Comment: It seems like it is loaded through an api call with this url: https://www.reclamgymnasium.de/mobil/mobdaten/PlanKl20210618.xml?_=1623933794858

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: YES!!!!!! How? I've been looking for this sinc a week lmao

Comment: I'll make a quick second answer to explain how I found the info.

Answer (score 0):

As the information that Johann was looking isn't static but dynamic information, I'm making a second answer to explain how I got the info.

When visiting the webpage https://www.reclamgymnasium.de/mobil/plankl.html?Klasse=9.2

- Open the development tools of your browser (in my case it is firefox and I'm opening by pressing F12).
- When the develompent tools are open, click on the "network" tab, which will be empty at this point.
- Reload the page by clicking the reload arrow or by pressing F5.
- Now we can see requests being loaded in the "network" tab.
- As we are looking for data being loaded after page content, we look for "xml" or "json" responses in the "type" column.
- Right click the response which has either correct type and click "open page in new tab"
- If multiple responses match, test all matching until you find the information you are looking for.

In this case we found https://www.reclamgymnasium.de/mobil/mobdaten/PlanKl20210618.xml?_=1623933794858

Comment: Glad this helped! Goodluck with your script.